# Unable to open bootstrap modal window as a route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using bootstrap to display a modal and want it to be shown on click of a anchor tag as a route.
But i'm getting a module error & can't seem to figure out how to resolve it.

HTML

```
<div ng-view>
    <div ng-controller="DetailPageCtrl">
      <a href="#/profile">Click here to open modal!</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modalContainer">
        <div ng-controller="ProfileModalCtrl"></div>
    </script>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
      .when('/profile', {
          templateUrl : 'modalContainer',
          controller : 'ProfileModalCtrl'
      });
})
app.controller('DetailPageCtrl', function($scope) {
   console.log("detail page");
});
app.controller('ProfileModalCtrl', function($scope, $modal) {
    $modal.open({templateUrl : 'modal.html'});
});
```

Code in plnkr :
http://plnkr.co/edit/VbvuWzLqkICFzBYI9sL5?p=preview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Demo is plagued with problems. You haven't included angular-route.js. You didn't provide a default path using `otherwise` and you placed html within `ng-view`

```
/* include script tag with `angular-route.js , then inject as dependency*/
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'default'
  })
    .when('/profile', {
      templateUrl: 'modalContainer',
      controller: 'ProfileModalCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    })
});
```

```
<div ng-view><!-- leave empty --></div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/33572YOSA2s89uEiLmKB?p=preview)**</kbd>

You will also run into problems declaring same `ng-controller` in markup as in route config...pick one or the other

Comment: I have pretty much the same problem as this question - though still can't get it working - care to take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21883559/opening-a-modal-in-a-route-in-angularjs-with-angular-ui-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Your plunker is missing the `ngRoute` dependency. In newer versions of angular, `ngRoute` is a separate library that needs to included separately and declared as a module dependency to your app module:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/angular-route.js"></script>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Also, your routes are not fully defined.

Also, your templates (`<script type="text/ng-template">`) are defined inside the `<div ng-view>` element. `ng-view` is a directive which will replace the content of host div element when route is resolved, so a better place for your templates is outside of `ng-view` element.

<kbd>[Fixed PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/hlbMLlhtiW3TK9hbTUj4?p=preview)</kbd>

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when('/profile', {
    templateUrl : 'modalContainer',
    controller : 'ProfileModalCtrl'
  })
  .when('/detail', {
    templateUrl : 'detail.html',
    controller : 'DetailPageCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/detail'});
});

app.controller('DetailPageCtrl', function($scope) {
 console.log("detail page");
});

app.controller('ProfileModalCtrl', function($scope, $modal) {
  $modal.open({templateUrl : 'modal.html'});
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.4/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.js"></script>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="DetailPageCtrl">
      <a href="#/profile">Click here to open modal!</a>
    </div>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="modalContainer">
        <div ng-controller="ProfileModalCtrl"></div>
    </script>

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```