# opening a modal in a route in AngularJS with angular-ui-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I am trying to do what was essentially answered here [Unable to open bootstrap modal window as a route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585541/unable-to-open-bootstrap-modal-window-as-a-route)

Yet my solution just will not work. I get an error

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal`

```
My app has the ui.bootstrap module injected - here is my application config

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap','ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'app.filters', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'app.controllers'])

    // Gets executed during the provider registrations and configuration phase. Only providers and constants can be
    // injected here. This is to prevent accidental instantiation of services before they have been fully configured.
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {

        // UI States, URL Routing & Mapping. For more info see: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '/views/index',
                controller: 'HomeCtrl'

            })
            .state('transactions', {
                url: '/transactions',
                templateUrl: '/views/transactions',
                controller: 'TransactionsCtrl'
            })      
            .state('login', {
                url: "/login",
                templateUrl: '/views/login',
                controller: 'LoginCtrl'                
            })

            .state('otherwise', {
                url: '*path',
                templateUrl: '/views/404',
                controller: 'Error404Ctrl'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }])
```

I have reduced my controller to the following:

```
appControllers.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {
    $modal.open({templateUrl:'modal.html'});
}]);
```

**Ultimately, what I am hoping to achieve is when login is required not actually GO to the login page, but bring up a dialog.**

I have also tried using the `onEnter` function in the `ui-router` state method. Couldn't get this working either.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Ok - so as it turns out, having both ui-bootstrap.js AND ui-bootstrap-tpls breaks this - After reading the docs I thought you needed the templates to work WITH the ui-bootstrap. though it seems all the plunkers only load in the ..tpls file - once I removed the ui-bootstrap file my modal works...Am i blind? or doesn't it not really say which one you need in the docs on github? -

Now i just need to figure out how to prevent my url from actually going to /login, rather than just show the modal :)

**update 2**

Ok, so by calling $state.go('login') in a service does this for me.

Comment: Your controller shouldn't need `'$modal'` as a dependency as you loaded `'ui.bootstrap'` in your app dependencies. Could you try removing it? (But leave the `$modal` in the controller function parameter) ;)

Comment: nope - now i get `ReferenceError: $modal is not defined`

Comment: Also checked to make sure that angular-ui-bootstrap.js is loaded after angular.js, and it is

Comment: Ok, and isn't `'ui.bootstrap.modal'` a separate module from `'ui.bootstrap'`? Maybe try loading it into your app or controller dependencies. I only use the modal from angular-ui-bootstrap and that's the way I load it.

Comment: I have the full js - least I believe i do - it contains this line: `.provider('$modal', function () {`

Comment: @glepretre it is not. @Daren, this is strange: `'ui.bootstrap','ui.bootstrap.tpls'` - you shouldn't need 2 different dependencies, `'ui.bootstrap'` should be enough. In any case a plunker  would give you an answer in no time...

Comment: I can remove the `'ui.bootstrap.tpls'` dependency - doesn't seem to break anything else. With regards to the plunker - I believe I pretty much copied this - sans the ngRoute as i am using ui-router http://plnkr.co/edit/33572YOSA2s89uEiLmKB?p=preview

Comment: Could it be that you are injecting 'ui-bootstrap' into app, and not appControllers?

Comment: @MattWay - no idea.. I just tried `var appControllers = angular.module('app.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap'])` and no joy - i must be using something so very wrong here..

Comment: Looks like you might have to try and recreate the problem in a fiddle/plunk

Comment: added one - though just like my solution, thats not doing a bloody thing either O_o

Answer (score 11):

Hi I had a hard time getting through the similar problem.
However, I was able to resolve it.
This is what you would probably need.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("managerState", {
      url: "/ManagerRecord",
      controller: "myController",
      templateUrl: 'index.html'
    })
    .state("employeeState", {
      url: "empRecords",
      parent: "managerState",
      params: {
        empId: 0
      },
      onEnter: [
        "$modal",
        function($modal) {
          $modal.open({
            controller: "EmpDetailsController",
            controllerAs: "empDetails",
            templateUrl: 'empDetails.html',
            size: 'sm'
          }).result.finally(function() {
            $stateProvider.go('^');
          });
        }
      ]
    });
});
```

[Click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/i1d3P8keTcMwWQ0sIn9h?p=preview) for plunker. Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not seem to close the dialog when pressing back though

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on something similar and this is my solution.

HTML code

```
<a ui-sref="home.modal({path: 'login'})" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openModal()">Login</a>
```

State configuration

```
$stateProvider
  // assuming we want to open the modal on home page
  .state('home', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/views/index',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
  })
  // create a nested state
  .state('home.modal', {
    url: ':path/'
  });
```

Home controller

```
//... other code
$scope.openModal = function(){
  $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'path/to/page.html',
    resolve: {
            newPath: function(){
                return 'home'
            },
            oldPath: function(){
                return 'home.modal'
            }
        },
    controller: 'ModalInstanceController'
  });
};
//... other code
```

Finally, the modal instance controller.
This controller synchronizes the modal events (open/close) with URL path changes.

```
angular.module("app").controller('ModalInstanceController', function($scope,    $modalInstance, $state, newPath, oldPath) {
    $modalInstance.opened.then(function(){
        $state.go(newPath);
    });
    $modalInstance.result.then(null,function(){
        $state.go(oldPath);
    });
    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
        if($state.current.name != newPath){
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel')
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You may create a state with the same `templateUrl` and `controller` as your page where you want to show the modal, adding `params` object to it

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root.start-page', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'App/src/pages/start-page/start-page.html',
        controller: 'StartPageCtrl'
    })
    .state('root.login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'App/src/pages/start-page/start-page.html',
        controller: 'StartPageCtrl',
        params: {
            openLoginModal: true
        }
    })
```

And in controller of the page, use this parameter to open the modal

```
.controller("StartPageCtrl", function($scope, $stateParams) {
    if ($stateParams.openLoginModal) {
        $scope.openLoginModal();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a handy hint to get this working. There are probably caveats, but it works for me. You can pass a `result` still but I have no need for one.

Using `finally` instead of the `then` promise resolve sorted this for me. I also had to store the previous state on rootScope so we knew what to go back to.

**Save previous state to $rootScope**

```
$rootScope.previousState = 'home';
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(ev, to, toParams, from, fromParams){
    $rootScope.previousState = from.name;
})
```

**State using onEnter**

```
$stateProvider.state('contact', {
    url: '/contact',
    onEnter: function ($state, $modal, $rootScope){
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
            controller: 'ContactCtrl'
        }).result.finally(function(){
            $state.go($rootScope.previousState);
        })
    }
});
```